# strange ' showing in formula bar but not in cell

Tags: excel

After doing a TransferSpreadsheet command to export data from Access to Excel, the data shows a strange ' in front of all the data. But this character only shows in the formula bar, it is not visible in the cells.

If I edit the cell and try to remove the ', it just comes back.

I've only left a few cells visible for confidentiality of my client.

Just wondering what is going on here...

[image]

Comment: That's a prefix denoting that the cell is text. Lots of resources online explaining it.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=excel+remove+single+quote+in+front+of+text

Comment: would of helped if i had put "apostrophe" in my search